# Stream Xbox One game content to another tv

Tags: xbox-one

I'm trying to stream my game content from my Xbox to another TV. Either by dlna/chromecast.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean, is that TV physically in your room, or do you mean any TV in general ? or even something else ?

Comment: Yeah, I have my system in one room and I wanted to stream it to another room.. Without physical moving the system or running a 25 HDMI cable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an PC/laptop with Windows 10, it's fully possible . You hook that PC/laptop to the tv you intend to play on (via hdmi), using the Xbox app, stream from your Xbox to the PC/laptop and Hey presto play on that tv. Just remember, your controller will still need connecting, if it's close enough, it will pick up the Xbox, if not, you will need the USB wireless dongle for the Windows 10 PC/laptop

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. While the Xbox can receive streams, it can't broadcast them as of now.

Source: [Xbox Wire article](http://news.xbox.com/2014/10/xbox-one-new-friends-snap-and-tv-features-on-xbox-one), experience with DLNA servers and clients